How to pronounce "the 1900s" and "the 1940s"?
How to pronounce "the 1900s"?:
(1a) the one thousand, nine hundreds
(1b) the nineteen zero zeros
(1c) the nineteen hundreds

How to pronounce "the 1940s"?:
(2a) the one thousand, nine hundred and forties
(2b) the nineteen forties
(2c) the nineteen hundred and forties

P.S.: All variants are mine. I don't know which are correct and which are not.

Conventionally, in the UK, it's the nineteen hundreds and the nineteen forties. Although FumbleFingers has a valid point that nineteen hundreds  can also refer to the whole of the 20th century. Maybe the context clarifies the meaning, or you could just say the first decade of the 20th century
I've never heard the nineteen noughties used.
I suspect that the period 2000 to 2009 being known as the noughties probably started because either twenty hundreds doesn't roll off the tongue (in my opinion) or it's a play on words being a homophone for naughties.

I am British, born in 1952, and I am afraid that I see 'the XX00s' meaning the whole century as a creeping Americanism.

The answers should be (1c) the nineteen hundreds and
(2b) the nineteen forties.
Besides this question, to refer to the first decade of that millennium, we could say the nineteen noughties.

The Noughties is the decade between 2000 to 2009.

Edit
I add this entry from Cambridge Dictionary:

noughties noun [ plural ] mainly UK the period of years between 00 and 10 in any century, usually 2000–2010

and record of usage from Today South London, Tomorrow South London.  This is indeed rare but has been used.

But the nineteen hundreds validly references all years 1900-1999.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  I've edited my answer.

@FumbleFingers - until comparatively recently, I was accustomed to the 1900s being the decade from 1900 to 1909, and I still get annoyed when people say things like 'The American Civil War was in the mid-eighteen-hundreds'. To me the 1900s roughly span the death of Victoria and that of Edward VII, give or take.  I think of HG Wells getting jiggy, and straw boaters, and NOT Hitler and Tony Blair.

@MichaelHarvey - Me too. My late father always referred to the decade in which he was born as 'the 1900s', so  it puzzled me at first when I came across people referring to the Victorian era as 'the 1800s'.

@SeowjoohengSingapore - Noughties is a new coinage (Oxford says 1980s) and I have never heard it used to refer to any other decade than 2000-2009.

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  Can we use a word coined after an era in question to describe that era? Also, would this entry from Cambridge be valid here: noughties noun [ plural ] mainly UK the period of years between 00 and 10 in any century, usually 2000–2010? If so, I will include it; else I will delete  that earlier mention.

We can and do, but dictionaries seem to be divided as to whether noughties can be used to refer to the first decade of any century or just the 21st. I can find no examples online of eighteen/nineteen noughties.

I’m sorry to learn that several Brits are pained by the use of the n hundreds to mean an entire century. This usage does have the strong benefit of not suffering the off-by-one problem.  Me, I often have to do a quick check to remind myself, exactly what years are referred to as, for example, “the seventeenth century.” I say to myself, “OK, the twentieth century is the years with the 19. So the seventeenth must comprise the years with 16.” A confusing step that’s unnecessary when that century is called “the 1600s.” Granted, this does create its own problem with the decade 1600–1609.

Hi, @Kate Bunting, this phrase is indeed rare, and I found just one usage At the Dean Swift--a pub presumably named after the once-beloved racehorse of the nineteen noughties in Today South London, Tomorrow South London.

Only yesterday I wrote The OED has no cited usages since the 1800s in an answer on ELU. If I'd been speaking, obviously I'd have said "the eighteen hundreds". When reading and commenting on this answer yesterday, I checked Google Books and found just two instances of the collocation *"nineteen noughties"**. It's certainly not a common usage.

@SeowjoohengSingapore - surely the pub (like the racehorse) was named after Dean (Jonathan) Swift, the author of Gulliver's Travels?
